# SpringBatch scheduler executing multiple times

Tags: java, spring-batch, scheduler

I have not come across any solution to my problem after a lot of search.
I am scheduling my Jobs with spring batch scheduler in springjob.xml.

```
<bean id="startScheduler" class="com.myapp.MyServiceStart" />
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="1"/> 
 <task:scheduled-tasks  scheduler="myScheduler">
         <task:scheduled ref="startScheduler" method="runMyService" cron="*/5 * * * * *" /> 
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

But runMyService is starting multiple times and increasing with each wchduled re-run. I need my service to run just once with each scheduled re-run.

Comment: The `cron` expression looks invalid. What's the expected execution interval?

Comment: Looks like you have one too many *.  Try  `*/5 * * * *`

Answer (score 0):

May be one reason is that after execution again they reschedule.So the next schedule depends on the execution time.

```
public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule() {
        synchronized (this.triggerContextMonitor) {
            this.scheduledExecutionTime = this.trigger.nextExecutionTime(this.triggerContext);
            if (this.scheduledExecutionTime == null) {
                return null;
            }
            long initialDelay = this.scheduledExecutionTime.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
            this.currentFuture = this.executor.schedule(this, initialDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            return this;
        }
    }
public void run() {
        Date actualExecutionTime = new Date();
        super.run();
        Date completionTime = new Date();
        synchronized (this.triggerContextMonitor) {
            this.triggerContext.update(this.scheduledExecutionTime, actualExecutionTime, completionTime);
            if (!this.currentFuture.isCancelled()) {
                schedule();
            }
        }
    }
```